# using javascript to determine ip works in chrome not firefox or ie

Tags: javascript, ip

I am using javascript to determine the visitors ip address. For what ever reason, it works in Chrome and not in Firefox, IE, or other browsers.

Here is my code:

```
function getIPAddress() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php", false);
    xmlHttp.send();

    var hostipInfo = xmlHttp.responseText.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < hostipInfo.length - 1; i++) {
        var ipAddress = hostipInfo[i].split(":");
        if (ipAddress[0] == "IP") return ipAddress[1];
    }

    return "unknown";
}
```

At the company I'm working for, I am behind a proxy. Could this be a proxy issue, or is there something wrong with this code? Thanks.

Just deployed my code to our test environment, and in IE, I receive a pop up saying 'This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?' If I say, yes, it works. If I say, no, it doesn't.

Comment: Did you try a POST method? Maybe it is a caching issue.

Comment: Two things: if that's running in a page from a domain other than "hostip.info", it won't work due to basic browser security rules, and (2) you're not waiting for the ajax request to finish anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use AJAX (which is what this code is), I STRONGLY suggest you use a 3rd party wrapper like jQuery. That will increase cross-browser compatibility greatly and  allows you to shrink your code down to something like this.

```
$.post('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php', function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

**Additional Point**

As `Pointy` mentioned, if your page is running on a different domain than `hostip.info`, you will need to setup a local PHP to fetch the data like this..

**localGetData.php**

```
die(file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php'));
```

**New Ajax**

```
$.post('localGetData.php', function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: could you give an example of setting up a local fetch the data from asp.net. I'm not using PHP and don't know the equivalent.

Comment: Im not particularly familiar with ASP.NET, so I really could not off the top of my head. Maybe this link will suffice? http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/285/httpwebrequest/rev/4

Comment: just realized i could get ip from server side with Request.UserHostAddress. at moment, get address of local machine, but i think that's because my computer and server both inside the same network.

Answer (score 0):

`for (var i = 0; i < hostipInfo.length - 1; i++) {` will cause to return "unknow" if `hostipInfo` has only one element, change to `for (var i = 0; i < hostipInfo.length; i++) {`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this works in Chrome is because it supports CORS which allows you to make this request cross domain.

Since the site doesnt appear to support